# Insert MAC Address from python into mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm recently want to insert mac address from bluetooth.discover_devices() into a mysql table.
But i always get *"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near ':EE:2D:A0:47:E4)' at line 1"*.
My MAC address from bluetooth.discover_devices() is 00:EE:2D:A0:47:E4.
I wonder why i cant store that use simple insert from python into mysql.
FYI, i already tried to print the addr and it shows my MAC address

Here is my code

```
import bluetooth
import MySQLdb

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,db)
cursor = db.cursor()

for addr in nearby_devices:
    cursor.execute("insert into user (macaddress) values (%s)" % addr)
    print ("%s" % (addr))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Use the proper way of passing arguments to your query provided by `.execute()` of your DB adapter. Never use string formatting on SQL queries. It leads to SQL injections and error like the one you are observing.

Comment: That would be: `cursor.execute("insert into user (macaddress) values (%s)", [addr])`

Comment: it works man thanks. yeah i already research about sql injection but still confused how that works. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
cursor.execute("insert into user (macaddress) values (%s)" % addr)
```

to

```
cursor.execute("insert into user (macaddress) values ('%s')" % addr)
```

Have a try!